# LINQ statment with .any() isnt returning. Loads forever

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq statment which runs perfectly, except that I only want to return items that have a specific value. When I add in a clause to the .any() it freezes up my browser. Is there a better way to do this, or optimize it?

let me just show you the two versions. One works pretty quickly, the other loads for ever. The difference between the two is the first line of the .where()

Working version:

```
var creat = (db.Creatures
    .Include("UserTypes")
    .Include("UserTypes.Carts")
    .Include("UserTypes.Carts.Items")
    .Include("UserTypes.Carts.Items.Details")
    .Where(b => b.UserTypes.Any(c => c.Carts.Any(tb => tb.Status == "Paid"))
    && b.UserTypes.Any(c => c.Carts.Any(cb => cb.Items.Any()))
    && b.UserTypes.Any(c => c.UserTypeID== UserTypeGUID))).Take(10);
```

What Im trying to do but isnt working. It loads forever:

```
var creat = (db.Creatures
    .Include("UserTypes")
    .Include("UserTypes.Carts")
    .Include("UserTypes.Carts.Items")
    .Include("UserTypes.Carts.Items.Details")
    .Where(b => b.UserTypes.Any(c => c.Carts.Any())
    && b.UserTypes.Any(c => c.Carts.Any(cb => cb.Items.Any()))
    && b.UserTypes.Any(c => c.UserTypeID== UserTypeGUID))).Take(10);
```

Comment: do something like `c.Bookings.Where(tb => tb.Status == "Paid")`

Comment: Have you checked if the server side code works or not? With the info you gave us, it could very well be that you get 0 results with the new filter on `tb.Status` and your client-side code doesn't handle it.

Comment: Probably a bad query plan or just an outrageous query to process. Capture the actual execution plan (maybe using SQL Profiler and the XML Showplan event) and post it somehow. The event is raised as soon as the query starts so you can kill it after that.

Answer (score 4):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question but your code could be refactored in the following way. Three of your conditionals involve looping over The `UserTypes` with an Any, you could just use one. Also there is no need for the `c.Carts.Any()` because if the `UserType` had no carts the second conditional would fail.
As @usr's comment suggested maybe the complex query is converted into some complex sql.

```
var creat = (db.Creatures
.Include("UserTypes")
.Include("UserTypes.Carts")
.Include("UserTypes.Carts.Items")
.Include("UserTypes.Carts.Items.Details")
.Where(b => b.UserTypes.Any(c => c.Carts.Any(cb => cb.Items.Any()) &&   
                                 c.UserTypeID == UserTypeGUID))).Take(10);
```